# Microsoft BotFramework v4 replace Dialog problem with Timers

Tags: c#, .net-core, botframework, azure-bot-service

I'm trying to use **System.Timers** Timer for async Task, but I'm geting the error "**Cannot access a disposed object**" when I'm tring to reset my dialog in Waterfallstep.

I've tried GC.KeepAlive but did not work. I'm using bot framework **SDK4** and **net core 3.1**.

I've tried **System.Threading.Timer** and the same error occured.

The proactive message does not meet my requirements to reset the whole dialog after sometime.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-howto-proactive-message?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp

I will appreciate your help with this situation.

**My code**

```
        {
            System.Timers.Timer timer;
            var dialogSet = new DialogSet(accessor);
            dialogSet.Add(dialog);
            var dialogContext = await dialogSet.CreateContextAsync(turnContext, cancellationToken);
            var results = await dialogContext.ContinueDialogAsync(cancellationToken);

            if (results.Status == DialogTurnStatus.Empty)
            {
                await dialogContext.BeginDialogAsync(dialog.Id, null, cancellationToken);
            }
            else
            {
                await dialogContext.ReplaceDialogAsync(dialog.Id, null, cancellationToken);
            }

            timer = new System.Timers.Timer(1000 * (60 * 1));
            timer.Elapsed += async (sender, e) => await dialogContext.ReplaceDialogAsync(dialog.Id, null, cancellationToken);
            timer.Start();
            System.GC.KeepAlive(timer);
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are lot of documentaries on this and most of the cases are similar to the current issue. You need to setup your controller action using `*PUT api/category*`

https://entityframeworkcore.com/knowledge-base/57952486/using-async-repository-pattern---cannot-access-a-disposed-object

Check the above link for using ***async Task***

Comment: Thanks for the answer. In this case I should do a request in "API/category" in each update in Timer ?

Comment: Yes, need to focus on PUT controller operation in API/category